# Symfony2 change entity field value depend on locale

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Entity called `Country`. It has the following fields:

```
id
nameDe //German Names
nameEn //English Names
```

Now i have a FormTyp where `Country` is a field from the type `entity` which will be set in the `FormBuilder`.

```
$builder 
    ....
    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                "class" => "Company\Project\ProjectBundle\Entity\Country",
                'required' => false
            ));
```

It all works fine, the `Country` Entries will be shown in the form, but always the german Names from the `nameDe` field.

I'm translating my application into english right now using a `locale` in my URL, which is the normal way to do so.

Now i want to display the english Countrynames from `nameEn` when the `locale` is englisch, how can i do this? I thought about the `PRE_SET_DATA` Event from the `FormBuilder`, but i'm a bit clueless and stuck. What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it fairly easily. The simplest way to do it is:

- Inject the locale via FormType constructor and store it in class field
- Use the value when building the form

**Constructor:**

```
private $locale;

public function __construct($locale){
    $this->locale = $locale;
}
```

Now, just add the `property` options:

```
$builder 
    ....
    ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                "class" => "Company\Project\ProjectBundle\Entity\Country",
                'required' => false,
                'property' => $this->locale
            ));
```

Another way, which I prefer, is to define your FormType as service and set it to inject `locale` automatically.